# Тег = тэг = метка = пометка?

Tags: синонимы, заимствования

> **Обрывки из реальностей. По тэгу Рим**
>
> Это не книжка. Это обрывки из реальностей – записи из личного
>   дневника. Точнее, только те, у которых стоит пометка Рим. То есть они
>   написаны в Риме и чаще всего они – о Риме.

Ничего (ли), что реальности во мн. ч.?

> пометка Рим

Рим надо кавычить?

Если автор хочет "тэг" - оставить? А метка = ли пометке?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > Ничего (ли), что реальности во мн. ч.?

Да тут как-то и в ед.ч. не очень смотрится... Уж очень заковыристая метафора. )

> > Рим надо кавычить?

Я бы сказал, что да, обязательно.

В книжке - "тэг"?! Нет, лучше "пометка". )